# Deactivate RSVP for Outlook for Windows with ICS calendar

Tags: windows, outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

I can't seem to disable RSVP in Microsoft Outlook for Windows by importing a ics file generated by my application.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:OTB:37965bfa-effe-4833-9ffe-94a035f3139f
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:37965bfa-effe-4833-9ffe-94a035f3139f
DTSTART:20230501T065000Z
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND:20230501T070000Z
LOCATION:Location
SUMMARY:summary
ATTENDEE;CUTTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=OPT-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPT
 ED;CN=Tad Molina;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:retyby@mailinator.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Informationen zum Termin:\nNachname: Molina\nVorname: Tad\nE-Ma
 il-Adresse: retyby@mailinator.com\nTelefonnummer: +1 876762-6963\nAktenzei
 chen: 342\nBemerkungen: Ut consectetur perfe\nTeilnehmer/in Anzahl: 9\n
ORGANIZER;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:test@foo.bar
DTSTAMP:20230424T123942Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Here what i want to remove after importing the `ics` file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4GCX.png)

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

I tried deleting the RSVP property from my ics file but nothing.